# How to copy date to cell with phpspreadsheet so it is sortable?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to save a table to Excel using PhpSpreadsheet.

One of the columns is a date, however Excel will not recognise it as a date and allow it to be sortable as one unless I manually run the 'Text to columns' procedure in Excel.

I've tried using this line to format it:

```
$sheet->getStyle('C2:C' . $row)
  ->getNumberFormat()
  ->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
```

I've also tried formatting the date in different date formats e.g.

```
'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'dd.mm.yyyy'.
```

The 'Text to columns' procedure would seem to suggest my data is tab delimited.

***How can I correctly format the date with PHPspreadsheet so Excel recognises it as such?***

Comment: I came with the exact same problem. Tried with encoding and decoding and didn seems to work. I've deleted headers just in case it expands the header format and still doesnt work.
Hope somebody can help for future issues

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to format your date into unix code, set the cell value and set the format code.
For reference: [Write a date or time into a cell](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell)

In your case:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$row= strtotime($row); //transform into unix timestamp
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExcel($row));
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('dd.mm.yyyy');
```